# unable to get defination of an index psypg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

i need to recreate indexes on a table as i have to insert a lot of data into the table.
i am trying to get the defination of an index in postgres using

```
SELECT pg_get_indexdef('start_date_sr_index_its'::regclass);
```

it works, but when i try to run this same command from psycopg2 it says relation does not exist

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "start_date_sr_index_its" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT pg_get_indexdef('start_date_sr_index_its'::regclass);
                               ^
```

i have tried to replace `'` with `"` but it says the same

Comment: You're connected to a different database / db server or your `search_path` is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier way to get index definition in postgres is to get it directly through the pg_index table instead of using utility function `pg_get_indexdef()`.

You can simply query

> SELECT indexdef FROM pg_indexes WHERE indexname = ''

you can also get `schemaname`, `tablename` and `tablespace` from this table.